# Download a folder to the FileSystemStorage

Tags: codenameone

In an app, I need to download html pages (along with css, images and js files) from server to the `FileSystemStorage` and then display it on device. With `Util.downloadUrlToFile` I can download the files individually but is there any way to download the entire folder to device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since there is no such concept of a directory in HTTP. You can download a file but you won't know there are other files next to it. One of the things apps do is parse the HTML/CSS to find other referenced files and download them. That's a HUGE pain.

Another option is to zip or tar the files together and unzip them locally.